# Understanding Node.js single-thread performance

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, performance

I have recently created a node.js program to simply time the execution of certain javascript functions. The code is simple, get given a function, run it a hundred times, and determine timing statistics from the hundred runs of data.

This is all being run on a single thread (no clustering, no workers, no IO components), and so the behaviour I see is confusing. Instead of the solid utilisation of a single CPU to crunch the numbers, I see a lot utilisation spread over multiple CPUs. I am curious if this is related to why I am finding node slower than Chrome (x3 slower or so).

[image: cpu timing of node execution]

I am trying to get execution to essentially restrict to one CPU so that I can parallelise the code using the cluster functionality. In the cluster implementation I have of the code (not the single threaded implementation above), I do not find much benefit in using more children. 1 child takes 95 seconds, and 2 children take 89 seconds, for example. For something as parallelisable as this, I was hoping for a greater performance increase.

Would anyone be able to shed some light on what is happening behind the scenes here, for someone that is relatively new to node? Is something causing a lot of context switching? And any ideas on how to increase performance?

The test code node is actually executing (though I have tried this with multiple pieces of code to the same result):

```js
var sum = 0.0;
for (var i = 0; i < 1e10; i++) {
        sum += Math.pow(i, 0.01);
}
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: What OS are you running this on? Most OSes don't dedicate processes to a single CPU. When a process is put to sleep (in order for other processes to run) and then woken up later (when it is the process's turn to get CPU time) it will simply be given the next available CPU. Some OSes can do CPU pinning which forces the OS to run the process on the same CPU as much as possible.

Comment: This is on Windows, so I can't avoid some process switching. However, when compared to something like a c program running, I observe the c program much more dedicated on a single CPU and utilising close to 100%, even with it being put to sleep from windows' process management.

Comment: Under the "Details"-tab in task manager, you can right-click on a process and set its cpu affinity to lock it to a single core.